# get first related object in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm having difficulty accessing the first related object within a template.

I'm using

```
{{ course.student_set.all[0].get() }}
```

but its throwing loads of errors. How do i get the first related object?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`{{ course.student_set.all.0 }}` Will do the trick for you, but I wonder why you want to only get the first student from your course in your template.

Comment: Well i wanted to get a random student. But the first will be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try `{{ course.student_set.all.0 }}`.  Template engine does not allow arbitrary code and method access syntax is different from normal Python code.  I recommend reading [this overview](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/templates/) to understand how templates work